# Ubuntu will not boot without the CD

Tags: boot, usb, live-cd, cd

I installed Ubuntu but it will not boot unless I have the CD in it. I tried reinstalling it and I still have the same problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: When you put the CD in are you sure it is your installed Ubuntu system you are booting into and not the live system? It's pretty much impossible for your system to boot an installed Ubuntu system just because the CD is in because the CD has nothing to do with the boot process unless your computer is set to boot from the CD before your bootloader which would mean that your are just booting into the live system!

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting your pc with the cd rom inside. Go to boot menu; make sure you format it properly. Are you using the try Ubuntu option instead of the Install option?